# all content going outside from navbar

Tags: html, css

when I change the resolution of screen contents are going outside from nav bar

```css
@media screen and (max-width:836px) {
   
    nav{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
   
    
}
```

```html
<nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="fp1.png" alt="" width="140px">
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="home.htm">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.htm">about</a></li>
                <li> <a href="explore.htm">explore</a></li>
                <li> <a href="sing in.htm">sing.in</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="searchbar">
                <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="search hear">
                <div class="searchlogo">
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                    search 
                </div>  
            </div>
```

this is the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIbkB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your contents are lorger that the container, you need to set your container objects to `display: flex;` and add `flex-wrap:wrap;` to it.